# MongoDB compare sub arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I try to check for discrepancies in our database, and for that I need to compare 2 arrays within the same element.

I'm not far but when comparing arrays with `.match({$expr: {$ne: ...})`, the order matters. So I would need to reorder those arrays to compare them.

My script currently looks like that:

```
db.users.aggregate()
    .match({"companies": { $exists: true, $not: {$size: 0} }})
    .lookup({
        from: "companies",localField: "_id", foreignField: "users.userId", as: "relatedCompanies"
    })
    .addFields({
        relatedCompanyIds: {
            $map: {
                input: "$relatedCompanies",
                as: "relatedCompanyId",
                in: "$$relatedCompanyId._id"
            },
        },
        
    })
    .match({$expr:{$ne:["$relatedCompanyIds", "$companyIds"]}})
```

Basically, each collection element contains an array `companyIds` and another array `relatedCompanyIds`, which are both a list of *ObjectIDs*.

Any idea about how to sort those arrays, or to compare two arrays within the same item without caring about the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$not` with [$setEquals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/) aggregation operator, performs set operation on arrays, treating arrays as sets. If an array contains duplicate entries, `$setEquals` ignores the duplicate entries. `$setEquals` ignores the order of the elements.

```
.match(
  {
    $expr: {
      $not: { $setEquals: ["$relatedCompanyIds", "$companyIds"] }
    }
  }
)
```

Similar condition `$ne` with `$setEquals` aggregation operator,

```
.match(
  {
    $expr: {
      $ne: [
        { $setEquals: ["$relatedCompanyIds", "$companyIds"] },
        true
      ]
    }
  }
)
```